# Grouping By Alias names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to group my station codes as shown below however my result set keeps outputting everything and `others` multiple times. I want to group everything by my alias names however for my station `others` it doesn't seem like it is grouping it.

```
WITH
        station as (
        SELECT
         CASE
            WHEN t.station='AB' THEN 'AB'
            WHEN t.station='AS' THEN 'AS'
            WHEN t.station='KF' THEN 'KF'
            WHEN t.station='PR' THEN 'PR'
            WHEN t.station='SV' THEN 'SV'
            WHEN t.station='RE' THEN 'RE'
            WHEN t.station='TVR' OR t.station='TDT' THEN 'TDT'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END AS 'station'
        FROM t

    )
        porders as (
        SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN t.station='AB' THEN 'AB'
            WHEN t.station='AS' THEN 'AS'
            WHEN t.station='KF' THEN 'KF'
            WHEN t.station='PR' THEN 'PR'
            WHEN t.station='SV' THEN 'SV'
            WHEN t.station='RE' THEN 'RE'
            WHEN t.station='TVR' OR t.station='TDT' THEN 'TDT'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END AS 'station',
        COUNT(*) AS 'p_orders'
        FROM a, t, v, station
        WHERE a.psn = t.psn
          AND t.highest_psn = 0
          AND v.detailno_i = a.detailno_i
          AND t.station!=''
          AND a.status=1
          AND v.order_type='P'
          GROUP BY t.station

)
        SELECT station.station, porders.p_orders
        FROM station join porders on(station.station=porders.station)
```

**Output**:

```
station|porders
---------------
 AB       2
 AS       4
 KF       3
 PR       10
 SV       2
 RE       20
 TDT      10
 Others    1
 Others    2
 Others    3
```

**Desired Output:**

```
station|porders
---------------
 AB       2
 AS       4
 KF       3
 PR       10
 SV       2
 RE       20
 TDT      10
 Others    6
```

Comment: Wait, what RDBMS are you using?, how is your second CTE working with no `GROUP BY`, but using an aggregation function?

Comment: Sorry, just made an edit to it I forgot to copy that part.. I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you're getting is due to the fact that you have three `t.station` values that get mapped to `Other` The statement `GROUP BY t.station` doesn't care that they get projected to `Other` in your Select.

To fix this you need to group by your case instead of the untranslated value `t.station`

```
GROUP BY
       CASE
            WHEN t.station='AB' THEN 'AB'
            WHEN t.station='AS' THEN 'AS'
            WHEN t.station='KF' THEN 'KF'
            WHEN t.station='PR' THEN 'PR'
            WHEN t.station='SV' THEN 'SV'
            WHEN t.station='RE' THEN 'RE'
            WHEN t.station='TVR' OR t.station='TDT' THEN 'TDT'
            ELSE 'Others'
        END
```

Comment: Wow didnt know I could do that.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, just a note that you can simplify your case statement a lot:

```
    CASE WHEN t.station in ('AB', 'AS', 'KF', 'PR', 'SV', 'RE') THEN t.station
         WHEN t.station in ('TVR', 'TDT') THEN 'TDT'
         ELSE 'Others'
    END
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I found this very useful as well :)

Answer (score 0):

For your last two lines, how about:

```
SELECT station.station, SUM(porders.p_orders) as tot_porders
FROM station join porders on(station.station=porders.station)
GROUP BY station.station
```